# Process miscomunication with mmap

Tags: c, file, process

I cant get this program to work.
It should convert capital letters to normal and vice versa, and numberso into three asterisks (***), and rewrite the file that i give as an argument with said changes, mapped into memory.
The parent process must do the letter conversion, and the child process must do the numbers. They must procceed in halves: the first half of the file, and then the second half of it. The first half seems to be doing fine, but the second one is all corrupted.

I tried making buffer a char *buffer, and using the various methos commented in the code, but nothing seems to work properly.
Here is the code and output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // Comprobamos que se haya proporcionado un nombre de archivo como argumento
    if (argc < 2) {
    printf("Error: se debe proporcionar el nombre del archivo como argumento.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // Abrimos el archivo en modo lectura/escritura
    int file = open(argv[1], O_RDWR);
    if (file < 0) {
        printf("Error: no se puede abrir el archivo %s.\n", argv[1]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    // Obtenemos el estado del archivo
    struct stat estado;
    if (fstat(file, &estado) < 0) {
        printf("Error: no se puede obtener el estado del archivo %s.\n", argv[1]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);// Función que se ejecuta cuando se recibe una señal
    }
    // Comprobamos que el archivo sea un archivo regular
    if (!S_ISREG(estado.st_mode)) {
        printf("Error: %s no es un archivo regular.\n", argv[1]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    // Mapeamos el archivo en memoria
    char *map = (char*) mmap(NULL, estado.st_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, file, 0);
    if (map == MAP_FAILED) {
        printf("Error: no se puede mapear el archivo %s en memoria.\n", argv[1]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    printf("\n---------------PROCESO DE LECTURA EN CURSO---------------\n");
    char texto ='\0';
    int lr = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < estado.st_size; i++) {
        // Comenzamos a leer el archivo
        if ((lr = read(file, &texto, 1)) < 0) {
            printf("\nError intentando leer el archivo\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        // Comprobamos que se está leyendo correctamente el contenido del archivo (y cuál es)
        printf("%c", texto);
    }
    
    // Creamos un proceso hijo
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        printf("Error: no se puede crear el proceso hijo.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (pid == 0) {
        // Proceso hijo
        // Esperamos a que el padre procese la mitad del archivo
        raise(SIGSTOP); // Paramos el proceso para esperar la señal del padre
        int mitadArchivo = estado.st_size / 2;
        // Obtenemos el tamaño final del archivo (con la sustitución de números por asteriscos)
        int tamanioFinal = estado.st_size;
        for (int i = 0; i < estado.st_size; i++) {
            if (isdigit(map[i])) {
                tamanioFinal += 2;
            }
        }

        // Redimensionamos el archivo para ajustarlo al tamaño final
        if (ftruncate(file, tamanioFinal) < 0) {
            printf("Error: no se puede redimensionar el archivo %s.\n", argv[1]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
                // Procesamos la segunda mitad del archivo
        char buffer[/*mitadArchivo*/estado.st_size];
        int j = 0, k = 0;
        printf("\n---------IMPRIMIR DESDE EL HIJO---------\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < estado.st_size; i++) {
            if (isdigit(map[i])) {
                // Si el caracter es un número, lo sustituimos por tres asteriscos
                buffer[j++] = '*';
                buffer[j++] = '*';
                buffer[j++] = '*';
            } else {
                // Si el caracter no es un número, lo copiamos tal cual al buffer
                buffer[j++] = map[i];
            }           
            printf("%c", buffer[i]);
            if (i == mitadArchivo) { // Hemos llegado a la mitad
                    memcpy(map, buffer, /*2*(estado.st_size + j)*/ mitadArchivo + j); // Escribimos la  primera mitad ya modificada
                    raise(SIGSTOP); // Paramos el proceso para esperar la señal del padre
                    printf("\nSegunda mitad del archivo: \n");
                    if (isdigit(map[i])) {
                        // Si el caracter es un número, lo sustituimos por tres asteriscos
                        buffer[k++] = '*';
                        buffer[k++] = '*';
                        buffer[k++] = '*';
                    } else {
                        // Si el caracter no es un número, lo copiamos tal cual al buffer
                        buffer[k++] = map[i];
                    }  
                    memcpy(buffer, map + (mitadArchivo + j), /*2*(estado.st_size + j)*/  tamanioFinal - (mitadArchivo + j)); // Leemos la segunda mitad que queda por transformar
                }
        }
        printf("\n");
    
        // Copiamos el contenido del buffer al archivo
        //memcpy(map /*+ mitadArchivo*/, buffer, j);
    
        // Modificamos el tamaño del archivo para que tenga en cuenta los cambios
        //ftruncate(file, 2*(estado.st_size + j) /*- mitadArchivo*/);
    
        // Finalizamos el proceso hijo
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    } else {
        // Proceso padre
        // Procesamos la primera mitad del archivo
        char buffer[estado.st_size];
        int mitadArchivo = estado.st_size / 2;
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < estado.st_size /*/ 2*/; i++) {
            if (islower(map[i])) {
                // Si el caracter es una letra minúscula, la convertimos en mayúscula
                buffer[j++] = toupper(map[i]);
            } else if (isupper(map[i])) {
                // Si el caracter es una letra mayúscula, la convertimos en minúscula
                buffer[j++] = tolower(map[i]);
            } else {
                // Si el caracter no es una letra, lo copiamos tal cual al buffer
                buffer[j++] = map[i];
            }
            if (i == estado.st_size / 2){
                sleep(1);
                // Copiamos el contenido del buffer al archivo
                memcpy(map, buffer, j);
                // Indicamos al proceso hijo que puede continuar
                kill(pid, SIGCONT);
            }
        }
            // Copiamos el contenido del buffer al archivo
            memcpy(buffer, map, j);
            sleep(1);
            // Indicamos al proceso hijo que puede continuar
            kill(pid, SIGCONT);
        
            // Esperamos a que el proceso hijo termine
            waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
            
            printf("\n---------IMPRIMIR DESDE LA SALIDA DESDE MEMORIA---------\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < estado.st_size; i++)
                    printf("%c", map[i]);
            printf("\n");
            
            // Finalizamos el proceso padre
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }

        
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
---------------PROCESO DE LECTURA EN CURSO---------------
esta 5 es 6 la
prueba 89 para 531 ver si
35 el programa 7 funciona

---------IMPRIMIR DESDE EL HIJO---------
ESTA *** ES *** LA
PRUEBA ****** P
Segunda mitad del archivo: 
ARA ********* ARA ********* ���c�

---------IMPRIMIR DESDE LA SALIDA DESDE MEMORIA---------
ESTA *** ES *** LA
PRUEBA ****** PARA ********* ���c���of�/����
```

Comment: Debris like that is almost always caused by a missing `NUL` terminator.

Comment: But the conversion is failing, it doesnt even reach the las word before everything turning into debris. How should i address that?

Comment: Step through in a debugger very carefully.